# Bootstrap confirmation dialog calling a javascript function

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a rails application page with a javascript function like below.

I would like to change the confirmation dialog box to a bootstrap confirmation. I am not sure if I do that I do I call the load_data() function to get data.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

```
jQuery(function(){

var form_changed = false;

$(document).on("click", "#comments span", function() {

  var version_id = $(this).attr("data-id");
  var data_field_id = $(this).attr("data-field-id");

  if (form_changed && !confirm("You have made changes to the form. Are you sure you want to leave without saving?"))
    return false;
  load_data();
  form_changed = false;

  function load_data(){
   $.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:"/products/"+product_id,
    dataType:"json",
    success:function(result){
      $('#' + data_field_id).val(result.value);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: https://github.com/ifad/data-confirm-modal

Comment: https://github.com/bluerail/twitter-bootstrap-rails-confirm use this gem to pop up like bootstrap on confirm

Comment: bootbox.js is a plugin made to handle bootstrap dialogs via javascript. Pretty neat. http://bootboxjs.com/

Comment: thx guys but I have look at those. the problem I am having is I want to call a javascript function when user clicked ok like above. I couldn't do it for some reason.

Comment: first you need to setup html for bootstrap modal in page and than invoked it when you need to display it